# R package "tree": what is the difference between minsize and mincut?

Tags: r, classification

The `tree` command for constructing classification trees (using the "tree" library) is configured using `tree.control`.  The `tree.control` help page explains the `minsize` and `mincut` parameters as follows:

```
mincut  
The minimum number of observations to include in either child node.
This is a weighted quantity; the observational weights are used to
compute the ‘number’. The default is 5.

minsize 
The smallest allowed node size: a weighted quantity. The default is 10.
```

To me, these two descriptions seem to say very similar things.  What is the difference between `mincut` and `minsize`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, for classification, `mincut` determines the minimum number of observations required for *each class* where `minsize` is the minimum number of observations required for a node.

For an example suppose that I have 14 observations in a node and am deciding whether to split. If 11 are in class A and only 4 in class B then I shouldn't split because I don't have at least 5 of each class. If I had 10 in class A and 5 in class B then I could split.

Answer (score 2):

I do not agree with the accepted answer. My interpretation is that:

1. `minsize`is the smallest-sized node that you will consider splitting up into two child nodes.
2. `mincut`  is the minimum size of the child node. If you plan to split a node, each of the two child nodes must be at least mincut in size. Because of this defintion, `minsize` should be at least `2*mincut`

```
ir.tr <- tree(Species ~., iris)
tree(Species ~., data=iris, control=tree.control(nobs=nrow(iris),mincut=2, minsize=2)) #Error because mincut cannot be greater than minsize/2
tree(Species ~., data=iris, control=tree.control(nobs=nrow(iris),mincut=2, minsize=1) # Works fine
```

Comment: I've never used the `tree` package, so after researching `mincut()` and `minsize()`, your answer is the clearest. I believe the accepted answer only clearly explains `mincut()` and does not explain `minsize()`.